# Как "поймать" тап в нижней части UITableView, где ячеек уже нет?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Есть UITableView, который занимает весь контроллер, но в этой таблице несколько ячеек с небольшой высотой, в которых находятся UITextField и которые не занимают экран полностью.

Как тапнув по пустому месту снизу ячеек, скрыть клавиатуру?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift 4:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

// MARK: - View Lifecycle

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    configureTableView()
}

// MARK: - UI Events

@objc func tableBackgroundTapped(tap: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print(tap)
    tableView.endEditing(true)
}

// MARK: - Private Methods

private func configureTableView() {

    // ...

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tableBackgroundTapped))
    tableView.backgroundView = UIView()
    tableView.backgroundView?.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}
```

Нашел ответ здесь:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41555961

Проверил - работает )

Answer (score 0):

[image: Скриншот]

Посмотрите атрибут tableView в сториборд